# How to fetch settings of an existing DynamoDB table (specifically, streams) from an external resource in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

**Introduction**

I'm working on a project where I use AWS CDK to manage my cloud resources. In this project, I have DynamoDB tables that are not managed by the CDK, but I need to fetch their settings, specifically the Stream specification (whether the stream is enabled or not, and if so, the type of the stream).

**Current Approach**

Currently, I'm using Table.fromTableName to import the table:

```
const table = Table.fromTableName(this, 'ExistingTable', 'existing-table-name');
```

However, this does not allow me to access the table's stream details.

**Issue with the `ITable` interface**

I'm aware of the `tableStreamArn` property in the `ITable` interface, but it doesn't provide me with the stream settings, just the ARN (and it's optional, meaning it might not even be set).

**Question**

Is there a way in AWS CDK to fetch an existing table's settings, specifically the stream settings? I'd like to manage these settings via CDK and it's important for me to ensure that the settings are correct before proceeding with my application logic.

Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CDK [AwsSdkCall](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsSdkCall.html) interface to call `DescribeTable` for DynamoDB which will provide you the required details of the stream (if its enables, stream view type, arn etc...).